# Can't get object values in the form

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I can't get object values in the form to edit/update. getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productName')
    at UpdateProductComponent.ngOnInit (update-product.component.ts:63:33)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2576:22)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2545:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2496:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11622:21)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:12812:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11631:9)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:12858:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11348:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11657:13)
```

in my productservice.ts I got :

```
  getProductById(id: number){
    return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.baseUrl}/getProductById/${id}`);
  }
```

which i was able to get the id/productId fine,

In my main component I was able to redirect to new page/UpdateProductComponent fine with this:

```
updateproduct = (productId: any) => {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/updateproduct',  productId)
};
```

in my UpdateProductComponent i got this :

```
  product: IProduct;
  id: any;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.productService.getProductById(this.id).subscribe((data: Product)=>{
            this.product = data;
      console.log(this.product),              // retrieves the data fine
      this.updateForm.patchValue({
        // productId: this.id,                // works 
        //   productName: 'asdas',            // works 
        productId: this.product.productId,    // doesnt work
        productName: this.product.productName // doesnt work
      })
    });
  }
```

I can verify data is retrieved fine in network tab > under payload for that product as well in this format:
[{"productId":"2","productName":"23123","productDescription":"wqeq","productCategory":"qewqweq","units":23}]

*** Upadte ***
after updating my service to  Observable I am not getting the error but the values are still not getting populated

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this in your service

```
getProductById(id: number): Observable<Product> {
   return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.baseUrl}/getProductById/${id}`);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the log of this console.log(this.product)?

Comment: sorry error is gone, but its still not populating though ..here is the partial log: update-product.component.ts:39 [{…}]
all-products.component.ts:37 All products 
all-products.component.ts:39 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
update-product.component.ts:39 [{…}]
all-products.component.ts:37 All products 
all-products.component.ts:39 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
update-product.component.ts:39 [{…}]0: productCategory: "computers"productDescription: "gaming computer next gen"productId: "4"productName: "G600 cpu"units: 7[[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: Show me the response of Product when you subscribe to the service

Comment: thats the only time i call tat service - getProductById.

Answer (score 0):

Your attached JSON response is a `Product` **array**.

```
[{"productId":"2","productName":"23123","productDescription":"wqeq","productCategory":"qewqweq","units":23}]
```

While the service is expected to receive and return a **single** `Product` item.

Modify the `getProductById` in `ProductService` to return the Observable of `Product` item by getting the first item from the array via rxjs `.map()`.

```js
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';

getProductById(id: number): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/getProductById/${id}`)
    .pipe(map((response: Product[]) => response[0]));
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ceurkw?file=src/app/product.service.ts)

With this fix, it will fix why you can't bind the value getting from the API response to the form controls as mentioned in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72654075/8017690).

---

**Note:**

```js
this.updateForm.patchValue({
  productId: this.product.productId,
  productName: this.product.productName,
});
```

replaces with:

```js
this.updateForm.patchValue(this.product);
```

as discussed in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72654075/8017690).