# how to display object value in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, object

How to display object value in forms in angular. In browser developer tools I am getting the object and its values fine. But can't populate the values in the form.

In *.ts file i got:

```
console.log(this.product),              // {"productId": "3", "productName": "G500 cpu", "productDescription": "gaming computer", "productCategory": "computers", "units": 5 }
this.updateForm.patchValue({
        // productId: '23128',                // display 23128
        //   productName: 'asdas',            // display asdas
        productId: this.product.productId,    // doesnt display anything
        productName: this.product.productName // doesnt display anything
        // productId: this.product,    // display [object Object]
        // productName: this.product // display [object Object]
      })
```

in *.html I got:

```
    <form [formGroup]="updateForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="productId">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="productName"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: no errors Aakash. It just doesnt display anything

Comment: Odd behavior. But anyway you can just provide the whole object to form without specify each property (assume that the property names from the object variables and form controls are matched): `this.updateForm.patchValue(this.product)`.

Comment: thank you Yong. but its still not displaying anything. 
console.log(this.product) = 
{
    "productId": "3",
    "productName": "G500 cpu",
    "productDescription": "gaming computer",
    "productCategory": "computers",
    "units": 5
}
console.log(this.updateForm.value) = 
{
    "productId": "",
    "productName": "",
    "productDescription": "",
    "productCategory": "",
    "units": ""
}

Comment: Hi, the root cause of this question is due to the newly created question and provided the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72666354/8017690). Suggest closing/removing this question to remove redundant and this question seems unable to reproduce and provide the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning each control value patch whole value of product object,
just make sure form control name and object variable name should be matched.

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wt4gta?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      productId: new FormControl(''),
      productName: new FormControl(''),
      productDescription: new FormControl(''),
      productCategory: new FormControl(''),
      units: new FormControl('')
    });
    
    var product = {
      productId: "3",
      productName: "G500 cpu",
      productDescription: "gaming computer",
      productCategory: "computers",
      units: 5 
    };
    this.updateForm.patchValue(product);
```

Comment: thank you aniket, but its still not displaying anything. console.log(this.product) = 
{
    "productId": "3",
    "productName": "G500 cpu",
    "productDescription": "gaming computer",
    "productCategory": "computers",
    "units": 5
}
console.log(this.updateForm.value) = 
{
    "productId": "",
    "productName": "",
    "productDescription": "",
    "productCategory": "",
    "units": ""
}

Comment: It is working @termine.. Please check stackblitz example. the code is working there

Comment: it works for me when i have static values, it wont, when i get the values from object through backend. see my actual post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72650991/cant-get-object-values-in-the-form